# VBA code efficiency/potential memory leak?

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I have the following code in VBA which flips hebrew letters in each word in excel (omits english numbers and the rest:

```
Sub reverseHebrewInSelection()
   Application.Calculation = xlManual
   Dim c As Range
   For Each c In Selection
       c.Value = reverseOrderHebrew(c.Value)
   Next c
   Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub


Function reverseOrderHebrew(ByVal str As String) As String

Dim str2 As String
str2 = ""
Dim engLettersCount As Integer
engLettersCount = 0
For i = Len(str) To 1 Step -1

   If engLetter(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
        Do While ((i - engLettersCount) <> 0)
            If engLetter(Mid(str, i - engLettersCount, 1)) Then
                    engLettersCount = engLettersCount + 1
            Else
                Exit Do

            End If
        Loop
        'not english letter or end of string
        str2 = str2 + Mid(str, i - engLettersCount + 1, engLettersCount)
        i = i - engLettersCount + 1
        engLettersCount = 0
        getOut = 0
   Else
        str2 = str2 + Mid(str, i, 1)
   End If

Next i
reverseOrderHebrew = str2
End Function

Function engLetter(ByVal char As String) As Boolean

   If char < "א" Or char > "ת" Then
        engLetter = True
   Else
       engLetter = False
   End If
End Function
```

when i run this code on a pretty big selection the excel instance seems to get stuck and not respond. The code executes fine on smaller selections. The pc power is decent.

I know that my algorithm's efficiency is O(n^2) but it is still not supposed to stick the whole running process.

I suspect a memory leak but can't find it (garbage collector in vba?)
Any help please?

Thanks!

Comment: "when i run this code on a pretty big selection the excel instance seems to get stuck and not respond. " ->> "I know that my algorithm's efficiency is O(n^2) " . Yep,. That's what will happen for big N.

Comment: Thanks Mitch. The thing is that when I divide the needed input into say 5 parts it executes a few seconds each but completes the work in the end. when I put all the needed input it's stuck...

Comment: break into code in debugger. Is this condition safe?  -->  "Do While ((i - engLettersCount) <> 0)" what happens if it goes negative?  Infinite loop....

Comment: How big is a "pretty big" selection?

Comment: I checked the condition and changed it to not run when the condition goes negative. same problem... could you explain why it executes ok when i divide the input and stuck when the whole input is passed? doesn't it imply a memory issue more than run time thing? (I'm new to programming!)

Comment: Tim, it starts to "not respond" on selection of 30000 cells when in approximately 50% of it the work is just to skip the cell because its empty, 25% is to run on cell's string one time and go to next because it is english letters or numbers (O(n)). and the rest is hebrew+english short strings which take some work inside...

Comment: Later versions of Excel will do this for long running loops.  It's not actually locked up, and will eventually complete if you leave it long enough. To avoid the "not responding" on long run times, put a `DoEvents` in the loop. That said, the efficiency of your code can be dramatically improved.  For a start don't loop over a range, use a variant array instead.  There are plenty of examples on SO to get you started.

Comment: Yes - add `DoEvents` and add a progress counter. I suggest you don't jump to conclusions about memory leaks and freezing until you've done some analysis on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this version of your algorithm - it's a little bit (~2x) faster in my testing (but I don't have any Hebrew text to test with, so I used the cutoffs shown...)

```
Function reverseOrderHebrew2(str As String) As String

Dim i As Long, c As String, sOut As String
Dim tmp As String

    i = Len(str)
    sOut = ""
    tmp = ""
    Do While i >= 1
        c = Mid(str, i, 1)
        If c < "a" Or c > "l" Then
            tmp = c & tmp
        Else
            If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
                sOut = sOut & tmp
                tmp = ""
            End If
            sOut = sOut & c
        End If
        i = i - 1
    Loop
    If Len(tmp) > 0 Then sOut = sOut & tmp

    reverseOrderHebrew2 = sOut
End Function
```

The other comments also have good suggestions - depending on how much text there is in your cells, the process of reading/writing the cell values may be more or less of a factor, and using a variant array may gain a lot of performance (as long as there are no formulas in your selection, which would get overwritten if you used that approach)

Comment: Thank you guys. For now, after I added DoEvents inside the loop it stopped the "not responding" issue. Thanks for the efficiency improvement suggestions. I'll try to implement them in my future codes..

Comment: Tim, thank you. Your algorithm works fine and seems to be correct.

Comment: No problem - note that if your string are mostly Hebrew text it might be faster to reverse the whole string using `StrReverse` (which is very fast) and then just reverse the "english" sub-parts.

Comment: +1 I'd certainly go the variant array. Stripping the non-Hebrew characters with a regexp means the string could be flipped without a build.